# React : Enter key click on the unexpected button

Tags: reactjs, forms, button, react-redux, enter

First of all, I am a beginner in React and React Native, and I am taking on a project. So, sorry if you don't have al the details, ask me what you need if you have an idea of the issue. And I am not fluent English, so I apologize for that.
The code is a form, containing an input, and 2 butons. The first one to add a file, the second one for submitting the text.
When I test it on my laptop, android mobile or even on ios simulator, if I press enter key, everything works fine.
But when my CTO tries it on his iphone 12, the enter key clicks on the addFile button, in the web app or in the web viw of the react native mobile app.
Does somebody know where does it comes from ?

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        if (messageValue === "") {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            // On post le message
            postMessage();
            // On reset l'input
            setMessageValue("");
        }
    };
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setMessageValue(e.target.value, cas.id);
    };

    return (
        <ContainerReponse>
            <ChatFormInput
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                type="text"
                label="Envoyer votre message"
                value={messageValue.message}
                onChange={handleChange}
                valueToActive={messageValue}
                required={true}
            >
                <SendButton disabled={!messageValue ? true : false}/>
            </ChatFormInput>
        </ContainerReponse>
```

And this is the button element of the `<SendButton/>` component :

```
<button disabled={disabled} type="submit" value="Envoyer" className="sendButton orange send-message">
    Envoyer
</button>
```

Thank you for you kindness

Comment: You should show the related code. Is the button marked `type="button"`?

Comment: this is a button type submit

Comment: That would explain it. Try making it `type="button"`.